# Grouping a SQL result set in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops

Say I have a query the following query run:

### Edit

Added order clause because the real sql statement has one.

```
SELECT description, amount, id FROM table ORDER BY id
```

In this instance, the ID is not unique to the dataset.  It would return something like this.

```
    Description    Amount    ID
    -----------    ------    --
1    Hats            45       1
2    Pants           16       1
3    Shoes           3        1
4    Dogs            5        2
5    Cats            6        2
6    Waffles         99       3
```

What  I need to do is enclose each section of IDs in it's own div (So rows 1,2,3 in one div, 4,5 in another div and 6 in it's own div).

There are tons of solutions to this but I just can't think of one that isn't overly complicated.

I want to be able to keep the SQL how it is and somehow sort the data set in PHP so that I can loop through each section of the dataset while looping through the dataset as a whole.

Some kind of array would work but the structure of it is stumping me.

How can I get this to work?  PHP solutions would be idea but theoretical will help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple serial solution might look something like this:

```
$curId = '';       // track working id
$firstDiv = true;  // track if inside first div

// open first div
echo '<div>';

// foreach $row
{
    // when id changes, transition to new div, except when in first div
    if ($row->$id != $curId) {
        if ($firstDiv) {
            $firstDiv = false;
        } else {
            // start new div
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div>';
        }
        $curId = $row->$id;  // track new current id
    }

    // display contents of current row
}

// close last div
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: I like it!  It's almost identical to what I had in my head on about 40 lines shorter and actually works.

Comment: @MobyD: You would need to make sure you are sorting by `id` in your result set, and it should work nicely.

Comment: Without an order_by on the query (which there isn't), this would not work

Comment: @orourkek: Agreed, that would have to be added to the query.

Comment: You're right, I didn't have an order_by in my pseudo code.  But there is in my actual code.

Answer (score 4):

See if something like this works for you.

```
// execute query: Select description, amount, id from table

$results = array();

while ($row = $query_result->fetch_array()) {
    if (!isset($results[$row['id']])) $results[$row['id']] = array();
    $results[$row['id']][] = $row;  // push $row to results for this id
}

// later on
foreach($results as $id => $data) {
    // output div based on $id
    foreach($data as $datum) {
        // output individual data item that belongs to $id
    }
}
```

Comment: @sabre :) Yeah at this point in my career I've typed code similar to that principle many times

Comment: Yeah pretty standard approach when you can't directly modify the query.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the id in temp variable, if the next one is different close the div and open new div

Comment: Without an order_by on the query (which there isn't), this would not work

Comment: Ah  you are right, withour order_by the solution is going to be more complicated.

Comment: @orourkek: OP mentioned in a comment to my post that there is an order by on the actual query, just not in the example given in the question.   So this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming associative arrays for the db results:

```
$final = array();

foreach($results as $result)
{
    $final[$result['id']][] = $result;
}
```

This leaves you with an associative array `$final` that groups the entries by ID

Comment: Wont you only get one result for each id using this approach though? As `$final[$result['id']] = $result;` this will always overwrite the current entry in that position I think `$final[$result['id']][] = $result;` would work though.